# C++/Qt Q_OBJECT macro causes an error

Tags: c++, qt

I've just started programming in Qt framework. Following is a very simple program:

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>

class MyClass : public QObject
 {
     Q_OBJECT

 public:
     MyClass() {}
 };

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    MyClass *c = new MyClass();
    return a.exec();
}
```

But I receive following error when I try to compile & run it:

In function `MyClass`: 

undefined reference to `vtable for MyClass` 
But when I remove the *QObject* macro everything works fine. Please note that the class is defined in the same file as the main function. 

I'm using Qt version 4.7, running on Win 7. 
What is causing this issue?

**Update:** I get the same error when I define my class in a separate header file. mytimer.h:

```
#ifndef MYTIMER_H
#define MYTIMER_H
#include <QtCore>

class MyTimer : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    QTimer *timer;
    MyTimer();
public slots:
    void DisplayMessage();
};


#endif // MYTIMER_H
```

mytimer.cpp:

```
#include "mytimer.h"
#include <QtCore>

MyTimer::MyTimer()
{
    timer = new QTimer();
    connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(DisplayMessage()));

    timer->start(1000);
}

void MyTimer::DisplayMessage()
{
    qDebug() << "timed out";
}
```

And this is the main.cpp:

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include "mytimer.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    MyTimer *mt = new MyTimer();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Show the command(s) you are using to compile the code please.

Comment: Qt2.7 is quite old... have you tried a newer version? 4.8 is the latest, I think.

Comment: @tmpearce It was a mistake, it's 4.7.4

Comment: Try calling the QObject constructor: MyTimer::MyTimer : QObject(NULL) {...}

Comment: Can you paste your build process, I suspect that that is where the issue lies.

Comment: I assume that's from an IDE? Visual Studio? Some other?

Comment: @Ivo I tested it. It didn't help.

Comment: @timday I'm just compiling it using the Run (Ctrl+R). How can I see the compile codes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to compile it using qmake, which is going to create mock methods for your custom QObject class. See [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/moc.html) about more on generating moc files.

Since your example doesn't contain header files, it is not parsed, and no moc files are generated. You need to declare MyClass in a separate header file, and run moc generation tool.

Comment: while this may be helpful, you don't **need** to compile with qmake; you do have to configure things properly though, no matter which compile/build system you use.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using QT Creator you should cleanup up your project and execute qmake, in the build menu.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever u apply some changes first clean your project, then run qmake, and the finally build your project...